# Is there a way to run a .NET Core Service that uses OS authentication to run RMAN backups as systemd?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, rman

I have a service set up in C#/.NET Core and part of its functionality is to launch RMAN for Oracle at a specified time each day. These functionalities all work perfectly running as the Oracle user but not as root or running as systemd(even if I include the parameter to run as oracle in the init file).

Error when trying to run RMAN as root:
[Error as Root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4QBU.png)

ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

The code in C#:

```
string oraHome = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_HOME");
            //execute powershell cmdlets or scripts using command arguments as process
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = $"{oraHome}/bin/rman",
                Arguments = $"NOCATALOG TARGET  / CMDFILE {RMANObjects.Backup}RMAN_{RMANObjects.sn}.rcv LOG {RMANObjects.Backup}backup_log_{RMANObjects.sn}.txt",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            //start powershell process using process start info
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = processInfo;
            process.Start();
```

RMANandLogMover init/service file

```css
[Unit]
Description=RMANandLogMover
DefaultDependencies=no


[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/home/oracle/app/RMANandLogMover/8.25Logmover
ExecStart=/home/oracle/app/RMANandLogMover/8.25Logmover/RMANandLogMover
Environment=ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
User=oracle
Group=backupdba
RemainAfterExit=yes


[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: why dont you write a simple bash script for it?

Comment: WHY would you want to run rman as anything but the oracle software owner, usually 'oracle'?  I can't think of a single good reason.  That aside, your environment probably isn't properly set - in particular ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID.

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is not all environment variables are set. I suggest you to invoke `oraenv` first and make sure that you are using oracle's os user, not any other

```
export ORACLE_HOME=<path>
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. oraenv
```

first code this, then run RMAN :)